# Why setting App Attest environment to production removes the App Attest capability in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

Look at [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6xOHbJAbtvk4ZYIHtIi6cPQKig0oxzY/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate what I mean.

What I have done (according to [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider?authuser=0#install-sdk)):

1. Enabled the App Attest in Firebase console.
2. Added the App Attest capability
3. Changed the App Attest environment to `production` in the `.entitlements` file.

But each time I changed the environment to `production`, the App attest capability disappeared. And when I re-added the App Attest capability, the environment reset to `development`. And the cycle continues.

Moreover, my app always gives an error saying `App Not Registered` while in fact, it is. So I thought maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

After setting the `environment` to `production` and the App Attest capability disappeared, I re-run the app from Flutter, and it works.

So apparently, we do not need to worry if the `App Attest` capability is not shown. I think the most important is the certificate in the https://developer.apple.com has the App Attest checked.

[image]